# asterisk - use a different "SIP CoS mark"

Tags: asterisk, sip

On my asterisk server, when i do a sip reload, i get the message "Using SIP CoS mark 4", followed by a registration time out.

I need to make that statement say "Using SIP CoS mark 5".  How do I change the SIP CoS mark 4 to SIP CoS mark 5?

Answer (score 1):

In `sip.conf`, there are four parameters that control the `TOS` settings: `tos_sip`, `tos_audio`, `tos_video` and `tos_text`. `tos_sip` controls what `TOS` `SIP` call signaling packets are set to. `tos_audio`, `tos_video` and `tos_text` control what `TOS` values are used for `RTP` audio, video, and text packets, respectively.

There are four parameters to control `802.1p` `CoS`: `cos_sip`, `cos_audio`, `cos_video` and `cos_text`. The behavior of these parameters is the same as for the `SIP` `TOS` settings described above.

By default, the CoS is already set to 5 for audio traffic.  Signalling is set to 3.  In all honesty, those values are pretty standard.  Its unusual to change them in the majority of environments.  I'm really not sure why you would see CoS mark 4.  There is nothing using that by default.

You can read more info here: https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/IP+Quality+of+Service

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why, but I had to reboot my server.  Now things are magically working again, and asterisk is back in CoS mark 5.  Now instead of doing `sip reload` in CLI, I do a `/etc/init.d/asterisk restart` from bash.